# Athena Query Engine 3: HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a series of athena tables that get compiled from millions of small s3 json files each week. The data is partitioned. However, after upgrading to Athena query engine 3, I am suddenly receiving the following error when I attempt to compile the data files:

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Please reduce your request rate. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: SlowDown;
```

I have tried looking at AWS recommendations and all say that I should partition the data (which I already do) or wait (which I have also done).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: All you can do is to wait for S3 to scale. If you are impatient, you can open a support ticket and they will address it for you.

Comment: Thanks - can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by wait for it to scale? Is this specific to my account? What is the wait time influenced by / how long should I expect for it to take?